# Fastest way to build a list

Tags: python

What would be the fastest way to build a list of 1M elements? So far, what I am doing is the 'standard'

```
l = []
for elem in elems:
    # process xml element to get id
    l.append(id)
```

What would be the most performant way to do this?

Comment: My bet is on `list(elems)`

Comment: Do you really need a list?  When you have that much data, it is usually best to work with generators and lazy evaluation in mind.

Comment: There is also l = elems[:]